# NSURLConnection couldn't Cancel?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I do the following:
`NSURLConnection` loads url1   ，
i cancel it   ，
then，
`NSURLConnection` loads url2 ，
However the connection seems to continue to load url1 until finishing.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: Yes. Seeing how exactly you are using NSURLConnection would be very helpful to understanding the problem.